# Auto Sync Windows XP time on Boot

Tags: windows-xp, sync, date-time

I have an old PC with a defective CMOS battery, and every time the clock is reset, I have to log as admin in Windows XP and set the date manually, then I can sync from the server.
As this computer has parental control to protect children to use this computer between some periods, I would like to perform this date/time sync automatically on boot.
How can I do this?

Comment: Why not replace the cmos battery?

Comment: Because it is soldered on the motherboard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [Karen's Time Sync](http://www.karenware.com/powertools/ptsync.asp), configured to start and sync on logon, it seems to do everything I need.

Edit: in fact, Karen's Time Sync does not seem to be able to sync when a limited user logs in, so I replaced it with [NetTime](http://nettime.sourceforge.net/), that works perfectly !

Comment: Have a similar problem, and of course can set the time after boot using WIndows date & time or Internet time, but it seems that every 60 minutes or so Windows will re-sync with the defective RTC.